# How do I show up a floating window when script running

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make an app to download videos from Youtube. And I wrote a script and script has no argument or option. Getting variables from the clipboard. And it is my function to do it.

```
def check_clipboard():
    from tkinter import Tk
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    result = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
    print(result)
    return result
```

I am using this code (below) to caught clipboard changes.

```
clipboard_value_0 = check_clipboard()

try:
    while True:
        clipboard_value_1 = check_clipboard()
        sleep(1)

        if clipboard_value_1 != clipboard_value_0:
            print(clipboard_value_1)
            clipboard_value_0 = clipboard_value_1
            ...
```

It is working well but command prompt is always showing up and it is not friendly. Can I do this in backgroud and how do I show up a small floating icon in screen to show user script is running. And if clipboard change, execute script again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write below command before where you want to show floating window.

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=bar).start()
```

**Note-** Above code will help you run parallel tasks

And then make a same function as given below anywhere you want.

```
floating_window = Tk()
floating_window.geometry('+650+350')
floating_window.wm_overrideredirect(True)

# Progress bar widget
progress = Progressbar(floating_window, orient = HORIZONTAL,
            length = 200, mode = 'determinate')

# Function responsible for the updation
# of the progress bar value
def bar():
    import time
    progress['value'] = 20
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

    progress['value'] = 50
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

    progress['value'] = 100
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

    progress['value'] = 150
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)
    progress['value'] = 200

    floating_window.destroy()

progress.pack()
```

**Note-** Cotsimize it by according to you program, note how it will take time

#### If you want to demo

Copy the run the whole code who is given below

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import threading

floating_window = Tk()
floating_window.geometry('+650+350')
floating_window.wm_overrideredirect(True)

# Progress bar widget
progress = Progressbar(floating_window, orient = HORIZONTAL,
            length = 200, mode = 'determinate')

# Function responsible for the updation
# of the progress bar value
def bar():
    import time
    progress['value'] = 20
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

    progress['value'] = 50
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

    progress['value'] = 100
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

    progress['value'] = 150
    floating_window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)
    progress['value'] = 200

    floating_window.destroy()

progress.pack()

# This button will initialize
# the progress bar
# Button(floating_window, text = 'Start', command = bar).pack(pady = 10)
threading.Thread(target=bar,daemon=True).start()

# infinite loop
mainloop()
```